# Sort by index in Clustered Columnstore Index

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table for use in DW. Which will be perfect for **Clustered ColumnStore Indexing.**

However, I would really like to maximize the performance for the queries and therefore want to make a **specific order of the clustering** since I know that most of my queries will be on Date and what product.

But I can't seem to find an option.

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn511016.aspx) a clustered columnstore index `"Cannot include the ASC or DESC keywords for sorting the index. Columnstore indexes are ordered according to the compression algorithms. Sorting would eliminate many of the performance benefits."` Therefore you either need to use a standard clustered index, or not specify the order.

Comment: Well my implementation is a DW solution so I need the Clustered ColumnStore. Thx for the answer @GarethD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it.

That said, a normal table with the correct indexes is going to be faster than a Clustered Columnstore table. The only time I recommend using Clustered Columnstore is when you need to perform ad hoc queries against any column and thus can't create every possible index that you are going to need.

For my project I actually use both: a normal table, heavily indexed for commonly used queries and a clustered columnstore index for ad hoc queries.

Answer (score 0):

you can create non-clustered index for this :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Date
ON [dbo].[Table] (Datecolumn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has announced it for Azure SQL Data Warehouse(in preview).

> **[CREATE COLUMNSTORE INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**
>
> ```
> CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX index_name
>   ON { database_name.schema_name.table_name | schema_name.table_name | table_name } 
>  [ORDER (column [,...n] ) ] -- in preview
> [ WITH ( DROP_EXISTING = { ON | OFF } ) ] --default is OFF
> ```
>
> #### F. Create an ordered clustered columnstore index on a table with no index
>
> ```
> CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX cci ON Sales.OrderLines
> ORDER ( SHIPDATE );
> ```